# Defining boolean logic operators(v, ^, XOR, ->, <->)

Tags: c++11

Say we have `bool true = (P v Q) -> R`

How would I define an operator(or a function), so that the symbols(v, ^, XOR, ->, <->), would call the function that would perform the logic?

So, in example: `bool true = P v Q`, would call `bool or(bool a, bool b)`

Comment: In a string, you'll need a parser. In source code, that's not feasible in C++.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Are you asking how you would implement a function that takes `bool true = P v Q` as a string and parses it and determines to call `bool or(bool a, bool b)`? If so, what values should it use to call the `or` function? And what should it do with the answer?

Comment: You should overload a valid operator. But, first of all, you must to know who are valid operator in c, operator `v`is not an operator, and considere this: word `true` is a reserve word. Check this link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: @Quentin so without parsing it would not be possible?

Comment: @gurka, yes, I want it to determine on the go, because it won't be a string. In this case, I want `v` to call the function or(P,Q).

Comment: @illia you cannot write `bool true = (P v Q) -> R` directly in source code and have the compiler understand it. You can, however, write a parser that'll take it as input and dispatch function calls accordingly. But note that "how to srite a parser" is way too broad a question to be asked here.

Comment: @Quentin, Thanks. All I was wondering about, is if it was possible to write new operator(like + or -), for bool or int, so that it can perform calc on the go.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to define arbitrary infix operators in C++, and you also can’t use the name `true` as a variable name.

However, C++ already provides `||` for or, `&&` for and, `^` or `!=` for xor (for `bool`s, they’re equivalent), and `!` for not. If you want logical implication you’d best use `!P || Q`, and if you want iff, you should use `P == Q`.

Comment: xor is `^` (only one caret)

Comment: @gurka Huh, I thought there was a non-bitwise version of that, too. I rarely need it, but I’m surprised it doesn’t exist.

Comment: @DanielH, thank you, I'm well aware of the logic, I just thought there was a way to do it without parsing, of which I was not aware of.

Comment: @illia The C++ parser doesn’t support that. It reads `P v Q` as three identifiers in a row, which I don’t think is ever allowed. You could `#define v ||`, but that would cause a whole mess of problems in any libraries you used which assumed `v` was an identifier.

Comment: @DanielH for booleans, xor is `!=` ;)

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I mentioned that. But `&&` and `||` work on non-booleans even if they aren't `1`, while `1 ^ 2` and `1 != 2` both give the wrong answer for boolean logic. Usually not an issue, but it still feels weird not to have. I guess it's probably because you can't short-circuit xor like you can and and or.